# Proof divergence of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series, telescopic-series

I have the following series:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sqrt{n^2+1} -n$

and am suppossed to proof its divergence. The ratio and root tests aren't giving me any results and it's not a telescopic series, so there must be a way to prove it by comparison.

Unfortunately though I can't think of a series that is smaller than the given series and diverges.

Could anybody help me out here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you don't spot that $\sqrt{n^2+1}-n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}$.

Then you should still estimate $\sqrt{n^2+1} - n \approx \frac1{2n}$, for example because $$\sqrt{n^2+1} = n\left(1 + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{1/2} = n\left(1 + \frac{1}{2n^2} + \mathcal O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right)$$ by a Taylor series expansion or by the generalized binomial theorem.

Alternatively, because $\sqrt{n^2+1} - \sqrt{n^2}$ is approximately the derivative of $\sqrt{n^2+x}$ at $x=0$.

Once you have this estimate, we can try to prove an inequality $\sqrt{n^2+1} - n > \frac{1}{3n}$ or something like that. For this, we'd need to prove $\sqrt{n^2+1} > n + \frac{1}{3n}$, which is true (at least for all positive integers $n$) when we square both sides. Reversing the steps to turn this into a proof, we have

\begin{align}
 1 &\ge \frac23 + \frac{1}{9n^2} & \text{ if }n^2 \ge \frac 13 \\
  \sqrt{n^2+1} - n & \ge \sqrt{n^2 + \frac23 + \frac{1}{9n^2}} - n \\
 &= \sqrt{\left(n + \frac{1}{3n}\right)^2} - n \\
 &= \left(n + \frac{1}{3n}\right) - n \\
 &= \frac{1}{3n}
\end{align}
and now a comparison with the harmonic series is enough to show divergence.

Answer (score 4):

Well,

$$\sqrt{n^2+1}-n=\frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}\left(\sqrt{n^2+1}-n\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}$$

and see that $\sqrt{n^2+1}+n<\sqrt{n^2+2n+1}+n=2n+1$

so that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sqrt{n^2+1}-n\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}>\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2n+1}$$

and the last we know to diverge, thus, the initial one diverges.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's so obvious now that I see it!

Answer (score 2):

The general $u_n $ term is positive.

$$u_n=\frac {1}{\sqrt {n^2+1}+n} $$

but, for $n>0$,

$$n^2+1\leq 4n^2$$
thus

$$u_n\geq \frac {1}{3n} $$
it diverges.